patent invalidity search tool
I’m trying to save some time with patent invalidity searches. Currently I'm using Google patents and Lens; but it still takes a lot of time to read through the details of each reference.
Does anyone know of any good tools that can help with invalidity searches?
Would love to hear your recommendations or any experiences you’ve had with these kinds of tools. Thanks!

Searching is hard, are you already using classification searching and also looking in non patent literature?

This depends greatly by what field you are looking in. You can add Google Scholar to your toolkit. https://scholar.google.com
